# Undefined offset: 0 (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\reporting-soccerrave\resources\views\soccerrave\games\gamesListDetail.blade.php)

Tags: laravel

Am developing an application. A view page displays, when a field is displayed it redirects to another view blade with related id for the data.

The issue is that some displays fine while others showed this error:

> Undefined offset: 0 (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\reporting-soccerrave\resources\views\soccerrave\games\gamesListDetail.blade.php)

Source controller

```
    public function gamesList(Request $request)
{
  $games= DB::table('platform_games')
  ->leftJoin("platformgame_plays","platform_games.id","=","platformgame_plays.game_id")
  ->select("platform_games.id"
        ,"platform_games.name"
        ,"platform_games.description"
        ,DB::raw('COUNT(platformgame_plays.user_id) as no_of_people')
        ,DB::raw('SUM(platformgame_plays.count) as no_of_time')
        ,DB::raw('DATE(platform_games.created_at) as created_at'))
  ->groupBy('platform_games.id', 'platform_games.name')  
 ->orderByRaw('platform_games.name ASC')
  ->get();
    return view('soccerrave.games.gamesList');          
}
```

source view blade

```html
    <tbody>
        @foreach($games as $key => $game)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
                <td width="25%"><a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('gamesListDetail',$game->id) }}">{{ $game->name }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ $game->description }}</td>
                <td>{{ $game->no_of_people }}</td>
                <td>{{ $game->no_of_time }}</td>
                <td width="15%">{{ $game->created_at }}</td>
               
  
            </tr>
        @endforeach
            <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
                {{ $games->links() }}
            </td>
            </tr>         
    </tbody>
```

Distination Controller

```
    public function gamesListDetail($id = null)
{
$gamelists = DB::table("platform_games")
                 ->select(
                   "platform_games.id", 
                   "platform_games.name",
                   "game_player.username",
                   "game_player.game_id",
                   "game_player.points"                       
                 )
                 ->join(
                   "game_player",
                   "game_player.game_id", "=", "platform_games.id"
                 )
                 ->where('platform_games.id', $id)
                 ->take(5)
                 ->get(); 
    return view('soccerrave.games.gamesListDetail', compact('gamelists'));
}
```

Destination View blade

```html
    <tbody>
        @foreach($gamelists as $key => $gamelist)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
                <td>{{ $gamelist->username }}</td>
                <td>{{ $gamelist->points }}</td>
  
  
            </tr>
        @endforeach  
            <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                {{ $gamelists->links() }}
            </td>
            </tr>          
    </tbody>
```

**dd($gamelists);**

```
Collection {#299 ▼
#items: array:5 [▼
0 => {#307 ▼
  +"id": 4
  +"name": "Crazy Freekick"
  +"username": "Olajide"
  +"game_id": 4
  +"points": 595
}
1 => {#300 ▼
  +"id": 4
  +"name": "Crazy Freekick"
  +"username": "Samuel Poscabar"
  +"game_id": 4
  +"points": 7566
}
2 => {#304 ▼
  +"id": 4
  +"name": "Crazy Freekick"
  +"username": "ayoola"
  +"game_id": 4
  +"points": 15539
}
3 => {#301 ▼
  +"id": 4
  +"name": "Crazy Freekick"
  +"username": "Mooh9mobile1"
  +"game_id": 4
  +"points": 2406
}
4 => {#308 ▼
  +"id": 4
  +"name": "Crazy Freekick"
  +"username": "Mooh1"
  +"game_id": 4
  +"points": 1283
}
  ]
}
```

How do I resolve this error. Kindly help me out.

Comment: try remove this `{{ $games->links() }}`

Comment: I removed it, but the problem is still there

Comment: what's the *dd($gamelists)* ?

Comment: I have updated the code with  dd($gamelists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your destination controller to. The problem is you use ->get() method that returns a simple collection, not a PaginationInterface

```
public function gamesListDetail(Request $request, $id = null)
{
    $gamelists = DB::table("platform_games")
                 ->select(
                   "platform_games.id", 
                   "platform_games.name",
                   "game_player.username",
                   "game_player.game_id",
                   "game_player.points"                       
                 )
                 ->join(
                   "game_player",
                   "game_player.game_id", "=", "platform_games.id"
                 )
                 ->where('platform_games.id', $id)
                 ->paginate($request->input('limit', 5));

    return view('soccerrave.games.gamesListDetail', compact('gamelists'));
}
```